# Room db crashing due to column not being found

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

When running a query to return some data from the room database I am getting this crash on API 23 physical device.

LOGCAT

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_2
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
    at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '`allOrNothing`' does not exist
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
    at androidx.room.util.CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorUtil.java:108)
    at com.example.persistence.dao.DaoPieChart_Impl$2.call(DaoPieChart_Impl.java:169)
    at com.example.persistence.dao.DaoPieChart_Impl$2.call(DaoPieChart_Impl.java:164)
    at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have went through the table and model and cannot see the problem. The column name clearly exists.

TABLE

```
@Entity (tableName = "tableDistortedThinking")
public class TableDistortedThinking {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long pkDistortedThinking;

@ColumnInfo(name = "reframingId")
private long fkReframingId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "userId")
private long fkUserId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "allOrNothing")
private Integer allOrNothing;
```

MODEL

```
public class ModelPieChart {

private long userId;
private String twistedName;
private Integer allOrNothing;
private Date workoutDate;
private int DistortedThinkingCount;
```

QUERY

```
@Query("SELECT TableDistortedThinking.allOrNothing, COUNT(TableDistortedThinking.allOrNothing) AS DistortedThinkingCount, TableDistortedThinking.workoutDate, TableDistortedThinking.userId, TableDistortedNames.distortedName AS twistedName " +
        "FROM TableDistortedThinking " +
        "JOIN TableDistortedNames ON TableDistortedThinking.allOrNothing = TableDistortedNames.pkDistortedNameId " +
        "WHERE TableDistortedThinking.workoutDate >= (1000 * strftime('%s', datetime('now', :dateRange)))" +
        "AND TableDistortedThinking.userId = :userId " +
        "GROUP BY TableDistortedNames.distortedName " +
```

**They query is very long and is connected by UNION ALL but only this section is really relevant.
Any help root causing this crash would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using a version of Android Studio that has [Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#database-inspector), use it to examine your database.  It seems that your Room schema is not consistent with the actual database.

Comment: Im not sure how thats possible as I incremented the version number which destroys everything and starts over

Comment: You might find some clues by looking at the `_Impl` file Room generates for the DAO.  You'll find it in your project under `app` labeled `java (generated)`.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the backticks around `allOrNothing` in the error message about the column not existing.  Room adds backticks to quote table and column names in the generated SQL declarations (see the generated schema) but I would expect they would not get into the `_Impl` code for the query.

Comment: This appears to be a room bug.  See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157261134

Comment: @BobSnyder that would explain why this bug is only present on my old samsung s6 api 23 and not on my samsung s10 api29

Comment: updating the room version to  def room_version = "2.3.0-alpha02" fixed this issue. @BobSnyder if you want to submit a proper answer I will accept it since you found out it was a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This failure is caused by a Room bug that occurs on devices running API 25 or lower.  It is fixed in room version 2.3.0-alpha02.  See the [description in the Google IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157261134) for more details.